# I got an error with Flask can you help me?

Tags: python, flask, python-3.8

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return 'Hello! this is the main page <h1>HELLO<h1>'


if __name__ == '___main__':
    app.run()
```

I imported all modules that needed

I am new to flask

*Below is the traceback*

I will give moreinforamtion if you need:)

Thank all of the Stackoverflow community for help:))

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Toshiba/Desktop/python_temelleri/pythonwebsite.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
  File "C:\Users\Toshiba\Desktop\python_temelleri\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from jinja2 import escape
  File "C:\Users\Toshiba\Desktop\python_temelleri\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .environment import Environment
  File "C:\Users\Toshiba\Desktop\python_temelleri\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .defaults import BLOCK_END_STRING
  File "C:\Users\Toshiba\Desktop\python_temelleri\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\defaults.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .tests import TESTS as DEFAULT_TESTS  # noqa: F401
  File "C:\Users\Toshiba\Desktop\python_temelleri\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\tests.py", line 3, in <module>
    import decimal
  File "C:\Users\Toshiba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\decimal.py", line 3, in <module>
    from _decimal import *
AttributeError: module 'numbers' has no attribute 'Number'
```

Comment: Have you created a file called `numbers.py` somewhere?

Comment: Yes. I created.

Comment: There is a naming conflict going on - rename the numbers.py file to something else to resolve it

Comment: It has worked.Thanks